# SSH randomly disconnects from 3A+

Tags: wifi, ssh, windows, pi-3a+

I've been experiencing SSH disconnects and freezes ever since I got my Raspberry Pi 3A+. I connect to the 3A+ from my Windows machine using SSH over WLAN, and after about 5 - 10 minutes it hangs or disconnects with

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
```

or

```
Connection reset by {address of my RPi} port 22
```

If I try to reconnect, I get "Connection timed out", and if I ping "Destination unreachable". I usually have to either restart my PC (doesn't always help), or wait a while in order to connect again.

Some details:

- After one machine disconnects, connecting from another one **still works**, and the rpi itself is unaffected
- Disconnections happen on every device I own
- Connection seems to remain indefinitely if I don't do anything

I tried:

- Changing port
- Disabling wifi power managment on the RPi
- Disabling TCPKeepAlive
- Disabling Windows firewall

Comment: Knowing how your network is set up may help your cause.

Comment: @Seamus What information about the network is needed? Both the RPi and the windows machine are connected to WLAN.

Comment: Have you disabled the WiFi power management "feature".

Comment: @Dougie Wifi power managment on the RPi is turned off (as described in the post), the Windows wireless adapter setting is on maximum performance, and there is no power managment setting on the router.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a problem with your WLAN router. Check if the IP address of your Pi stays the same when this happens. It could be that your router gives the Pi a new address, or something similar is at play.

If the IP address stays the same, check the routing tables (`ip route` or a similar command) on machines which can and cannot connect to the Pi.

If the routing tables on your computers are identical, your router is using some sort of internal firewall to block inter-LAN connection. A common name for this option is "client/LAN/guest isolation". Make sure you disable it.

Comment: The address stays the same. I can reconnect from another machine using the same address after a disconnection.